# argocd & traefik: argocd unreachable

Tags: traefik, traefik-ingress, argocd

I'm struggling with exposing argocd using traefik.

Argocd is well deployed on my kubernetes. I'm able to reach it using port forwarding:

```
curl -I -k https://localhost:36651
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

I've deployed this ingressroute:

```yaml
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: argocd-server
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
  routes:
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`argocd.localhost`)
      priority: 10
      services:
        - name: argocd-server
          port: 80
    - kind: Rule
      match: Host(`argocd.localhost`) && Headers(`Content-Type`, `application/grpc`)
      priority: 11
      services:
        - name: argocd-server
          port: 80
          scheme: h2c
  tls:
    certResolver: default
    options: {}
```

When I'm trying to reach it, I'm getting an 404.

```
curl argocd.localhost
404 page not found
```

I've also tried to reach https directly:

```
curl -I -k https://argocd.localhost:8443/
HTTP/2 307 
location: https://argocd.localhost:8443/
```

It's getting me a redirection to `https://argocd.localhost:8443/`, which is the same that requested on `curl` command...

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to add `localhost argocd.localhost` to `/etc/hosts` file. And then access with port - `curl http://argocd.localhost:36651`

Comment: Since you get redirected,  add the `-L` flag to the curl command